# Problem reading cookie in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

In my application I'm trying to read the cookie value but in firefox4 it's reading it like

```
PHPSESSID=6obpuf73q9l7oelqjp49vi4f57; __utmc=111872281; __utma=111872281.346828356.1310972579.1310977402.1310984221.3; __utmz=111872281.1310972579.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); plugins_pn=0; __utmb=111872281.100.10.1310984221; pages_pn=0; selection=contract-hire
```

and in chrome it's reading it like

```
PHPSESSID=6obpuf73q9l7oelqjp49vi4f57;
selection=contract-hire
```

Some times in FF4 it works fine but 99% of the time it fails. Can somebody tell me how I can solve this problem.

**edit**

i am getting the cookie val as

```
var cookval = document.cookie.split('=')[2];
    var sel = cookval.split(';')[0];
//sel contains the desired value
```

Comment: We're going to need some more information. What happens when it fails? Can you easily reproduce the point of failure? Where is the code you're using?

Comment: You want to normalise the string returned over both browsers?

Comment: @john, this is your 10th question here. You should have figured out by now that we need to *see* your code in order to fix it.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: sry for not posting the code i thought it was irrelevant

Comment: tnx everybody the problem was with my proxy when i uses a proxy server on ff4 cookie val was not read properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to read and set cookie in javascript, use these little functions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

(When I use it, I also do a replace(/\+/g,' ') to get string with spaces)